# Determine one solution $\{x(t),y(t)\}$ of the non-linear system by introducing polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system

I need to determine one solution $\{x(t),y(t)\}$ of the non-linear system $$\dot x=y+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot (1-x^2-y^2)$$
$$\dot y=-x+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot (1-x^2-y^2)$$ by introducing polar coordinates.

In the beginning I started from inserting polar coordinates into $\dot x$ and $\dot y$: $$x=rcos\phi$$ $$x=rsin\phi$$
And I got $$\dot x=r\cdot sin\phi+ cos\phi(1-r^2)$$ $$\dot y=-r\cdot cos\phi + sin\phi(1-r^2)$$

But I don't know how to continue solving this problem,h ow can I determine the solution? Any tips?

Comment: Do you mean $y=r\sin\phi$?($\LaTeX$ tip, use `\sin` and `\cos`)

Comment: In order to complete conversion from cartesian to polar coordinates, one should write $\dot x$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$ by chain rule. This also applies to $y$ too.

Comment: First you need to get the calculus straight! If $x=r\cos(\phi)$ then $\dot x$ is not what you said, in fact $\dot x=\dot r\cos(\phi)-\dot\phi r\sin(\phi)$. Similarly for $\dot y$. Then the differential equations in $x$ and $y$ lead to differential equations in $r$ and $\phi$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich so now, should I compare $\dot x = \dot r \cos(\phi)- \dot \phi rsin(\phi) $to $\dot x=y+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot (1-x^2-y^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for starters:

By rearranging and dividing, you can deduce from your pair of differential equations that $$\frac{\dot{x}-y}{\dot{y}+x}=\frac xy$$
$$\implies\dot{x}y-\dot{y}x=x^2+y^2$$

Now if you substitute for $x,y$ and their time derivatives in terms of $r,\theta$, this equation reduces to $$-r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)\dot{\theta}=r^2$$

So $$\dot{\theta}=-1$$

Now using the first given equation, we have$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{dx}{d\theta}=r\sin\theta+\cos\theta(1-r^2)$$

And the left hand side is $$-\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta+r\sin\theta$$

So we end up with $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=r^2-1$$ and this is easily solved

Comment: After inserting (2a) (2b) (3a) and (3b) into (1) equation I got result $ \dot \phi= -1 $


$$x^2+y^2= \dot xy-\dot yx \qquad(1)$$
$$x=r\cos(\phi) \qquad(2a)$$
$$x=r\sin(\phi)\qquad(2b)$$
$$\dot x=\dot r \cos(\phi) - \dot \phi r \sin(\phi )\qquad(3a)$$
$$\dot y=\dot r \sin(\phi) +  \dot \phi r \cos(\phi )\qquad(3b)$$

$$r^2=-r^2 \dot \phi (\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi)$$
$$ \dot \phi= -1 $$

I calulcated it few times and still I get the same results. Morover, I do not understand how should I process next steps.

Comment: Yes you are right! And that makes it a lot easier. Please see my amended answer.

Comment: I don't understand why $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ As I went through the equation I have impression that is similar to what I wrote in the question: $$\dot x=r\cdot sin\phi+ cos\phi(1-r^2)
\dot y=-r\cdot cos\phi + sin\phi(1-r^2)
$$
I also don’t understand why $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=r^2-1$? Could you please explain it?

Comment: $\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{d\theta}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dt}$